# Django BooleanField doesn't work on edit form

Tags: python, django

My situation:

**Models.py**

```
class Box(models.Model):
    is_empty = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_add_now=True)
```

**Forms.py**

```
class BoxForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Box
        fields = (is_empty,)
```

**Views.py**

```
def edit_box(request, pk):
    box = get_object_or_404(Box, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BoxForm(request.POST, instance=box)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = BoxForm(instance=box)
    return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})
```

The problem is that when I enter into the template form and I want to change checkbox value I can't do it, it seems disabled and I dan't know why.

**EDIT**
**Template.html**

```
...
<form class="row gap-y" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
  <div class="col-2">
    <div class="checkbox">
        {% render_field form.is_empty class="form-control" %}
        <label for="id_description-is_empty">Is empty?</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
      <button class="btn btn-bold btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
...
```

Comment: try `fields = ['is_empty']` instead

Comment: It doesn't work, I can't change the checkbox value

Comment: pls show the template code

Comment: I've edited the post with html template

Answer (score 0):

Finally I achieve the solution:

I have to change **templates.html** like:

```
...
<form class="row gap-y" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
  <div class="col-2">
    <div class="checkbox">
        {{ form.is_empty }}
        <label for="id_is_empty">Is empty?</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
      <button class="btn btn-bold btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
...
```

In checkbox fields is not necessary to render class="control-form", then using browser console, look for field **id** and copy into label **for** param.